# Failed to connect to URL when trying to connect to api server

Tags: java, node.js, android-studio

So I am trying to set up a basic API server to get data from node js to java. I have a nodejs express server running on my LAN. I'm trying to send a post request in Java to a URL and get a response back, but I'm getting error `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:10000`. The node js express server is indeed running, and I also tried accessing the server from a javascript client using `fetch` and successfully got a response back. Where did I go wrong, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

**index.js**

```js
"use strict";
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const PORT = 10000;

app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

app.use("/api", require("./controllers/auth"));

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log("Error in server setup");
  console.log("Server listening on Port", PORT);
});
```

**auth.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const server = require("./server");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/server", server);

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```js
const server = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.json({ status: "success" });
};

module.exports = server;
```

**Main.java**

```js
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/api/server";
    String json = "{\"request\": \"requesting\"}";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(json);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("res code");
    System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(inputLine);
    } in .close();

    System.out.println("res string");
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that the full text of the error message? No 'connection refused', 'connect timeout', ...?

Comment: You wrote “I have a nodejs express server running on my LAN.” Are the client and server on different hosts or the same? 127.0.01 is the loopback address, so this code tells the client to try to connect to port 10000 on the same host. If the server is on a different host, you’ll need to use its LAN IP address.

Comment: @TimMoore Yeah, your suggestion made me think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was running the Java code inside Android studio emulator, and the emulated device was running on a separate network interface that was not bridged with the local LAN of the server machine, so it couldn't reach the URL `http://127.0.0.1:10000/api/server/`. The error can be solved by either creating a bridge with the emulated devices network interface or using a live public IP through the internet.